# Disable automatically calculation on a single sheet in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I would like to disable automatic calculation on a single Google sheet and then have a trigger, either by button or through some implementation of scripts, inserting a column, etc that will allow me to easily recalculate the entire sheet at will, but not automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not supported in Google Sheets at the moment. The best you can do is to create a switch condition logic with **`IF`** function:

```
=IF(X1=TRUE, your-formula-you-want-to-freeze(), )
```

If you work with volatile formulas you are able to delay them up to 1 hour in the spreadsheet settings:

[image: 0]

Comment: Actually that setting does not delay them up to 1 hour, it causes them to AUTOMATICALLY calculate after 1 hour even if you change nothing! So the complete opposite.